# Can exit pressure of nozzle be less than atmospheric pressure?

Tags: nozzle, pressure

This is kinda dumb question .I got 5psi pressure at outlet of the nozzle from open motor software. Is that possible because its less than atmospheric pressure 14.7 psi?
Am i missing out something?

Comment: Related: [Mach Diamonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_diamond)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure! That's called "overexpansion" because the flow is expanded too much to match the ambient pressure.

[image]

[ME 239: Rocket Propulsion: Over- and Under-expanded Nozzles and Nozzle Configurations](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.nasaspaceflight.com%2Findex.php%3Faction%3Ddlattach%3Btopic%3D33757.0%3Battach%3D829470&psig=AOvVaw1iixuhD_QFfPfUf6T5Z7Fo&ust=1598970346875000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCJjz-u_SxesCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ)

It has a negative effect on the thrust shown in this [equation](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/rockth.html):
$$Thrust = \dot{m}V_e +(p_e-p_0)A_e$$

if exit pressure ($p_e$) is less than ambient ($p_0$) the 2nd term in the thrust equation is negative.

As shown in the bottom right of the picture, things can get even worse if the pressure difference is large enough.

Comment: Does that mean if the igniton starts, the flow would be overexpanded which is inefficient?

Comment: @Auberron I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Meaning they are inefficient than perfectly expanded due to less thrust produced? I have heard overexpanded is efficient because the flow is narrower.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by inefficient. The usual figure of merit for engines is specific impulse. Since overexpansion reduces the thrust, it will reduce the specific impulse. To me, that makes it less efficient since you are burning the same amount of fuel and getting less thrust.

Comment: @Auberron: typically good engines will be overexpanded after ignition, and underexpanded around flameout, giving them optimal expansion (and performance) throughout most of the flight altitudes as air pressure drops.

Comment: @SF. So tweaking my design that is decreasing divergence angle isnt required for good engine?

Comment: @Auberron: Depends on how deeply you overexpand - I can't give you the exact metrics, but in general you should be maintaining near optimal expansion for most of the flight, so if you're still overexpanded at flameout altitude, that definitely needs tweaking.

Comment: Some engines intended for vacuum-only operation have radiatively cooled nozzles, so the nozzle skirt can get rather thin. In underexpansion the interior pressure is higher than the exterior, so the nozzle behaves like a pressure vessel: the stress in the nozzle material is tensional, so the material thickness doesn't have to be sized for prevention of buckling. If you try to test such an engine under significant exterior air pressure the nozzle overexpands the flow, putting the skirt in compression, and buckling failure can occur.

Comment: @TomSpilker agree, the shuttle OMS engines had a altitude limit of > 70K feet; below that their radiation-cooled nozzles could collapse.

Comment: I think the Apollo SPS engine was in the same boat.

Comment: @Tom Spilker How does overexpansion cause buckling. I doubt that.

Comment: Doubt it all you want, it's a fact.

Comment: See page 3-18 here https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/USA006500%20-%20Orbital%20Maneuvering%20System%20Workbook%20OMS%2021002.pdf